# How to read the html tags innerHTML value using css selector or xpath.?

Tags: javascript, html, css, xpath, css-selectors

My actual query is, I want to retrieve the HTML inner text value using css selector or xpath. I am able to acheive this by using document.getElementById but not using selectors, instead I can only able to print the tag element but not the text from it.

For Ex:

```
<li class="active">
  <span id="lastPrice">1,603.35</span>
  &nbsp;&nbsp;<span id="CAToday"></span><br>
  <span class="up" id="change">28.80</span>
</li>
```

From the above HTML, I want to print **1,603.35** using either

- Css   or
- xpath

Note: I have drilled the forum already but couldn't able to find required solution.

Comment: Like this? `document.querySelector('#lastPrice').textContent`

Comment: You are right, using document object I can, but I want to read using css / xpath ONLY, please. Perhaps, like '$$' or '$x'

Comment: I guess I don't understand what you mean by `using css selector`, since my comment uses a selector... I get the xpath part but not the css part, could you explain?

Comment: Can you please share the code you've tried so we can get more context?

Comment: I have tried on chrome console: $x("//*[@class='active']//span[@id='lastPrice']") and also 
$x("//*[@class='active']//span[@id='lastPrice']/text()"), then 
$x("//*[@id='lastPrice']")

Comment: Ok @FayazMd I got it, can you try this and tell me if it works for you? $x("//*[@class='active']//span[@id='lastPrice']")[0].textContent

Comment: @JamesGarcia: I think we are close, because,after making sure it is working on chrome console, I copied and pasted into my actual project work, where it is failing to parse.. As I understood the error is because, in my project we are not using '[0].textContent' as part of xpath query itself, that is, my function at work is not parsing javascript but understands css/xpath SELECTORS ONLY. Hence  xpath or css selector should not be an array based (which is javascript), query should be in a single line selector (with in quotes or parenthesis)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This XPath expression

```
string(/li/span[@id='lastPrice'])
```

With this well-formed XML

```
<li class="active">
  <span id="lastPrice">1,603.35</span>
  <span id="CAToday"></span><br/>
  <span class="up" id="change">28.80</span>
</li>
```

Result

```
1,603.35
```

Check in http://www.utilities-online.info/xpath/?save=07d6e884-4f7e-46cc-9aaf-904e6a440f50-xpath

Comment: it is working with the link you have provided, the exact thing I am looking and I was happy but, my happy doesn't lost long, :( I tried on chrome console, and it didn't work there, return value is an empty string. But, looks like you understood my query what I am looking for, please try to make it work on chrome console, I am also trying from my end.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thank you @ Alejandro: it is working on chrome console. when I use the following 

("string(//span[@id='lastPrice'])") OR
("string(//*[@id='lastPrice'])")

Not sure, why with single slash '/' is not working,

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the XPath version 2 `matches` function:

```
//div[matches(text(), 'Hello ?\w+ What would you like to do today \w+')]
```

which does allow regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Java Selenium (xpath example):

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@id='lastPrice']").getAttribute("innerText")
```

Python Selenium (CSS example):

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span#lastPrice").get_attribute("innerText")
```

Comment: That is javascript not css / xpath query. I am saying it is javascript because, [0].innerText or [0].innerHTML are using on the result of xpath selector. So, I am looking the same result within xpath / css selectors only. Something like, Kesh who already commented but when I tried it is not working :(

Comment: Don't know what tool and framework you are using, but you should be able to do this with `.getAttribute("innerText")".

Comment: Updated the answer with Java and Python options using xpath/css.

Comment: my query is not related to selenium though

Comment: ok. How about, `//span[@id='lastPrice']/@innerText`? It would be great which tool you are using to execute this script on.

Comment: this is the working solution from chrome console. `$x("//span[@id='lastPrice']/text()").forEach(function(el){console.log(el)})`